# Windows 7 takes 15 min before even downloading WIndows Updates

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

Every time I go to install updates--regardless of whether it's a single 2KB update or a dozen 300MB updates, the screen sticks at the "Please wait while windows..." for a good 15 minutes before it even starts the "1% downloaded..." etc.

The network is very fast on this machine--it appears to be something with Windows Update itself. I have a couple other Win7 machines at home the others begin downloading and installing updates immediately.  Related, likely, I very often get updates on this machine that simply fail.  After reboot I get the "Failure configuring windows updates...Reverting changes...".

I've done some research and have installed the October 2014 "Windows Update Readiness tool", and have cleared out various logfiles which seemed to be recommended be a large number of sites I generally trust (including here).

Yet the problem remains.  Does anyone have a suggestion, aside from a complete re-install of Windows, that I might try?
Thanks

Comment: make sure you have Update KB3050265 installed.

Comment: Registry backup?

Comment: No dice, I installed KB3050265 manually, still the same.  Process Explorer shows one of the SvcHost PIDs eating 25% cpu during this lag. Digging into the files that PID has open shows hundreds of handles to DataStore.edb, which I know to be part of the Windows Update apparatus.  That file is about 800MB, which doesn't seem out of line when comparing it to my other machines.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released a new WindowsUpdate Client Update to fix the slow Update searching/Installation.

**Installing and searching for updates is slow and high CPU usage occurs in Windows 7**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102810

**Download:**
**32Bit:** http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=fcd6bf5d-f004-4ca3-aa7e-1de462b91dd0

**64Bit:** http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=4fe566bd-31b1-4413-8c4c-412b52533669

Try this new Update and look if it speeds up the installation of Updates.

Comment: I will give these a try and see how they work.  There was a previous, similar update, but the KB number was lower so this one looks newer so maybe this one will really fix it.